# How to require 2 conditions

Tags: twig, operators, drupal-8

In a `twig`template with `Drupal 8`, I have a view.

I want this view to be displayed only if it has a result *and* if the current user is logged in.

I tested the code below but it doesn't work :

```
{% if logged_in and if view > 0 %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% if logged_in and view > 0 %}
```

You don't have to put it in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The condition should be :

```
{% if logged_in and (view > 0) %}
```

Comment: The parentheses are obsolete

Comment: why there is an extra 'if' in your condition?

Comment: Thank you it works without parenthesis. There was too much "IF"